# Flash Intro is embedded in a html, how do I integrate as my first page

Tags: plugin-recommendation, redirect, html, flash

I still learning how to work with WordPress. I know little of php. I have a flash intro that was done in a html file. I would like to find out how to integrate this as the first page on the website. The website is already set up to be a static website. I do not want the header, footer, navigation bar or anything else to display. I just want the intro then it automatic goes to the website.

If you click on http://jds-productions.com/Intro it will show you how I want it set up. I want this but when they type in http://jds-productions.com/ it displays just the intro first not the website, just like the link above does.

I already tried following Wordpress Creating_a_Static_Front_Page, that did not work. It displays all the other information and puts the intro in the body of the website. I don't know if it is due to the whole website is already set up as a static pages.

Can someone steer me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

rename your intro html file `front-page.php` and put it in your template directory, then create a dummy 'intro' page in WordPress and set that as your front page.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but don't forget that the `front-page.php` will need to be marked up correctly, including proper calls to `get_header()`, `get_footer()`, and anything else necessary to integrate the page into the rest of the site.

Comment: Sorry I am still learning WP. So I how do I set the dummy page up leaving it blank or do I enter some code? I don't want it the first page to get the header, footer and so on. I just want the intro displayed as the first page. It fills the entire screen up, then it redirects the the home page.

Comment: @Diane Marshall - leave the content area blank, the page is just a placeholder. your code will be embedded directly in the template file itself, as it is now in your static html page.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry I have another question. The intro is written completely in html, you said change it to a front-page.php. If I change it to a php it does not contain any php code, this will still work?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I went ahead & decided to try it and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about plugin
but you can edit your index.php file and set it to open default page as your flash html page

Or

Edit your htacces file to load some different index file.
Don't know more about htaccess, but try this if it works `DirectoryIndex filename.html`

Or set wordpress page as a static intro page,
http://wordpressapi.com/2009/01/26/how-to-add-the-flash-intro-in-wordpress-sites/

Comment: All the pages are already set up to be static. I read something like this on wordpress.org, but I really don't know php so I didn't know what code to input other than the template name. I tried that and it didn't work.